# android sensor logging duty cycling

Tags: android, logging, sensors

I have an app which logs sensor data to sd card. Logging is started/stopped with a button. For battery issues, I want it to modify it such that the app keeps reading sensor values and logging for X seconds, then sleeps for Y seconds, reads and logs for X seconds, sleeps for Y seconds ... How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall use [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html), which is designed for such a need. Look at an example [here](http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I want this cycling to be effective after the button pressed (i.e. while data is being logged). Can I still use TimerTask in onCreate? The code that I am trying to modify is [here](https://support.wimm.com/entries/21019398-source-code-a-sensor-logging-hack-um-app)